# Click a link and have a div change the PDF that is showing without going to a new page

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

Currently, I have a column that has some pdf names listed. In the next column, the pdf is embedded so it is displayed for the user.

What I need to accomplish is the following:

When a user clicks a document name in the first column, the pdf inside the second column changes to the corresponding pdf. All the while, it does not go to a different page. So the only thing that changes is the pdf that is displayed.

This is all coded in HTML and I'm hoping that someone will be able to help me out with this. I don't know if I need to use javascript with this or anything. I just can't find the solution anywhere on the web.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show code... html....

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery UI (Dialog) for that function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var fileName = "Sample.pdf";
    $("#btnShow").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: fileName,
            width: 540,
            height: 450,
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            open: function () {
                var object = "<object data=\"{FileName}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"500px\" height=\"300px\">";
                object += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{FileName}\">here</a>";
                object += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
                object += "</object>";
                object = object.replace(/{FileName}/g, "Files/" + fileName);
                $("#dialog").html(object);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<input id="btnShow" type="button" value="Show PDF" />
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell... put an iFrame on the second column and set the src with javascript

```
var myFrame = document.querySelector('#myIframe');

document.querySelector('a.mylink').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  myFrame.src = this.getAttribute('href'); // full public url

}
```